# Could not display /location "the location is not a folder" error - mount of other user displayed in Nemo file manager

Tags: linux, namespace, nemo

I added another say `user2` on Linux Mint system (19.2), logged-on and started X, then Nemo file manager. On the left on `Devices` expandable list I see links e.g. `/media/user1/data (/dev/sda5)`, when I click it, error is displayed `"Could not display /media/user1/data" "the location is not a folder"`. I guess the error is due to the fact `user2` have no permission to access the location (confirmed in CLI), but why Nemo displays those links in the first place, why not `/media/user2/data` and make new mounts for `user2` when `user2` clicks the view? How `userspaces` work here?